# Try to convert non whole number with $ sign to a float number in python

Tags: python

I have this number:

$13.96 and I want to make it 13.96 in python.

like this:
$13.96 >> 13.96

Comment: good for you...

Comment: That's not a number. Do you have a *string*, `'$13.96'`?

Comment: value = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', element)) I solved it this way

Comment: For `str  = "$13.96"` you can do `newStr = str[1:]` which will give you what you want. This is pretty simple, I advise you do some research next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
s = '$13.96'
new_s = float(s[1:])
```

Output:

```
13.96
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways to solve it and I get to this solution:

value = Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', element))